# Google Kubernetes Api Cron Job

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine, in that cluster there is a workload which runs every 4 hours, its a cron job that was set up by someone. I want to make that run whenever I need it. I am trying to achieve this by using the google Kubernetes API, sending requests from my app whenever a button is clicked to run that cron job, unfortunately the API has no apparent way to do that, or does not have a way at all. What would be some good advice to achieve my goal?

Comment: For this scenario you don't need a cron job. A simple bare pod or  a job would be enough, i would say. You can apply a resource on button push, for example with kubectl

Answer (score 2):

*This is a Community Wiki answer, posted for better visibility, so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

[`CronJob`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) resource in **kubernetes** is not meant to be used one-off tasks, that are run on demand. It is rather configured to run on a regular schedule.

[Manuel Polacek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7424896/manuel-polacek) has already mentioned that in his comment:

> For this scenario you don't need a cron job. A simple bare pod or a
> job would be enough, i would say. You can apply a resource on button
> push, for example with kubectl – Manuel Polacek Apr 24 at 19:25

So rather than trying to find a way to run your `CronJobs` on demand, regardless of how they are originally scheduled (usually to be repeated at regular intervals), you should copy the code of such `CronJob` and find a different way of running it. A [`Job`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) fits ideally to such use case as it is designed to run one-off tasks.